# How to use exported symbol on another kernel module?

Tags: linux, kernel, kernel-module

I've two kernel modules `A` and `B`, the module `A` exports the function `foo` using `EXPORT_SYMBOL(foo)`. To be sure if the symbol was correctly exported I executed `cat /proc/kallsyms | grep foo` which gives me the following:

```
0000000000000000 r __ksymtab_foo       [mod_a]
0000000000000000 r __kstrtab_foo       [mod_a]
0000000000000000 T foo [mod_a]
```

I want to use the function `foo` on module `B`, in order to do it I build the module `B` with the following Makefile

```
KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS := /path/to/mod/a/Module.symvers

obj-m = mod_b.o

# Get the current kernel version number
KVERSION = $(shell uname -r)

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

But even using `KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS` I receive a `error: implicit declaration of function ‘foo’` when I try to build the module `B`. Am I using the `KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS` right? Btw, build the two modules together isn't an option.

My kernel version is `5.4.0`

Comment: Even when `Module.symvers` contains a required symbol, for use that symbol in the code you still need to **include the header** file which declares that symbol.

Comment: This was my problem. Such a little mistake...thanks

Comment: Side note: _useless use of cat_.

Comment: @0andriy, this cat shows what symbols are exported, isn't it?

Comment: `grep foo /proc/kallsyms` would work same way without `cat`.